# How to validate an entry file with a list of string?

Tags: c#, dynamic, csvhelper

I need to write a file, but as I don't have a declared type (I'm using a dynamic object), I only have a string schema like `id;name;address`.
How can I validade the input stream with this schema?

It's using dynamic because the system doesn't need to know about this data.

But has a need to check if the data is following the schema provided.

Basically has a need to rewrite this extension method

```cs
public static void Write<T>(this string filepath, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T> records, string delimiter = "\t")
{
    var config = new CsvHelper.Configuration.Configuration { Delimiter = delimiter };

    using (var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filepath))
    using (var csv = new CsvHelper.CsvWriter(writer, config))
        csv.WriteRecords(records); 
}
```

and add a parameter for the schema

Comment: Your post is missing something. Where are you using dynamic and what is the correlation with you writing a CSV file ?

Comment: So you have a list of object, you write them in a CSV, But you didn't provide any mapping. So you read the Csv to see if it match the mapping you didn't provide? Is the paramter for the schema the mapping ?

Comment: The last paramter has to be  `ClassMap<T>`, if it's the question. And you will pass that to `csvWriter.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<TMap>();` So you won't have to validate the format the writer will

Comment: you just have to passe the type so if you need to pass an instance of Something passe the csvWriter.Configuration and put it in the constructor. Am I complety off, and didn't understand a single bit of your question? Because it's not clear and my cristal ball is running out of coffee.

Comment: CsvHelper is great for reading delimited files into a collection of strongly-typed objects. When it comes to writing, it may be much easier to just write your own code. That's especially true if you're dealing with unknown types where you'd have to add more complication just to get CsvHelper to read a set of properties. I'd try writing it myself.

Comment: If there's no declared type then what is the generic argument `T` for? Will it always be `dynamic`?

Comment: I wrote a little bit of code for this, but I could be going in the wrong direction. Where does this collection of objects come from? I understand that the type is unknown to the `Write` method, and that's okay. But do they actually have a type which is defined in your application? I don't think a generic argument makes sense in this case. You might want to pass `IEnumerable<object>` and a `Type` argument that specifies the type for each item in the collection. Or it may be safe to assume that every item in the collection is the same, in which case you would just look at the first type.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you meant generic object and not dynamic object.

If you want to make sure your records have the exact same property names as your schema list, you could do it like this.

```cs
public static void Write<T>(string filepath, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T> records, string schema, string delimiter = "\t")
{
    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

    var schemaList = schema.Split(';');

    if (properties.Count() != schemaList.Count())
    {
        throw new Exception("The given class does not have the same number of properties as the schema");
    }

    foreach (var name in schemaList)
    {
        if (!properties.Any(p => p.Name.ToUpper() == name.ToUpper()))
        {
            throw new Exception($"The given class is missing the property '{name}'");
        }
    }

    var config = new CsvHelper.Configuration.Configuration { Delimiter = delimiter };

    using (var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filepath))
    using (var csv = new CsvHelper.CsvWriter(writer, config))
    {
        csv.WriteRecords(records);
    }
}
```

If you want to make sure the records at a minimum have the property names in the schema, but you don't care if they have extra properties and you don't want those extra properties written, you could use the `DefaultClassMap` to set that up.

```cs
public static void Write<T>(string filepath, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T> records, string schema, string delimiter = "\t")
{
    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

    var classMap = new DefaultClassMap<T>();

    var schemaList = schema.Split(';');

    foreach (var name in schemaList)
    {
        if (!properties.Any(p => p.Name.ToUpper() == name.ToUpper()))
        {
            throw new Exception($"The given class is missing the property '{name}'");
        }

        var property = properties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.ToUpper() == name.ToUpper());

        classMap.Map(typeof(T), property).Name(property.Name);
    }

    var config = new CsvHelper.Configuration.Configuration { Delimiter = delimiter };

    using (var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filepath))
    using (var csv = new CsvHelper.CsvWriter(writer, config))
    {
        csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap(classMap);
        csv.WriteRecords(records);
    }
}
```